# VBA - Excel procedure is too Large

Tags: excel, vba, procedure

From reading the previous answers I understand I need to break up my code. I just need help doing it.

I have a large Select Case Procedure with approx 50 choices. Works Great! Until I programmed half of the "case is =" code for parsing the line if case is true.

It appears that my variable "Dataline" doe not pass to the subroutine. How do I pass the Line variable to my Sub.

```
Open fName For Input As #FileNum

While Not EOF(FileNum)
    'read in data one line at a time.
    Line Input #FileNum, Dataline

    'Read first three characters of line to determine Line Name
    LineName = Left(Dataline, 3)

    'Find line Name them parse
    Select Case LineName
        Case Is = "EH "     'Envelope Header
            EHsub 'Case sub routine (because I need to breakup code)
    End Select ' End of Select Case
Wend ' end of While Loop

Close #FileNum 'close the file
```

---

```
Sub EHsub()  'if envelope header = "EH " then parse dataline
    Field01 = Mid(Dataline, 1, 3) 'read 2nd data item
    ' I get an error here: "DataLine" is null
    'place date item in data worksheet
    Sheets("FannieData").Cells(Datarow, DataColumn).Value = Field01
End Sub
```

Comment: Um... `Sub EHSub(ADataLine)`, and in that code parse `ADataLine`, and call it with `EHLine DataLine`?

Comment: How similar are the parsing routines, i.e., what is going to end up being different in all of these Subs?

Comment: I have figured it out. To pass a variable from one sub to another the variable name cannot be the same. For example;

Sub Main
   Call Ehsub(Dataline)
End

Sub Ehsub(Dataline1) ' Need to be a different name, Then value flow through.
End

Answer (score 1):

either you go as per Alex McMillan solution (I'd do that) or you declare `Dataline` variable with a sufficiently broad scope

as for this latter alternative, should `EHsub()` and each of its callers be in the same Module then you would place

```
Dim Dataline as Variant
```

at the very top of it

should `EHsub()` callers be spread in different Modules then you'd place

```
Public Dataline as Variant
```

at the very top of any Module (no matter which one, but it could be fine to choose the one that first initializes `Dataline` variable)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing `DataLine` into your sub, so it doesn't know that variable exists.  Try something like this:

```
Select Case LineName
    Case Is = "EH "     'Envelope Header
        EHsub DataLine
End Select
```

---

```
Sub EHsub(DataLine)  'if envelope header = "EH " then parse dataline
    Field01 = Mid(Dataline, 1, 3) 'read 2nd data item
    ' I get an error here: "DataLine" is null
    'place date item in data worksheet
    Sheets("FannieData").Cells(Datarow, DataColumn).Value = Field01
End Sub
```